# Eclipse (or maybe windows is to blame?) won't print unless I fflush(stdout)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse and MinGW on my sister's computer running Windows 7.
While I was testing to see if everything is set properly, I noticed that this won't print anything:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;

    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("Enter a number... \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("You entered %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

instead, it just waits for input, and print the whole thing at once.
Here's how it looks:

```
345
Hello World!
Enter a number... 
You entered 345
```

It is only after I added a call to `fflush(stdout)` after `printf("Enter a number... \n");` that Eclipse printed it in the right order, meaning, this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;

    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("Enter a number... \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("You entered %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Works exactly as expected.
It is worth mentioning that I opened a separate C++ project and tried the same thing:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int x;
    std::cout<<"Hello!\n";
    std::cout<<"Enter a number\n";
    std::cin>>x;
    std::cout<<"you entered "<<x;
}
```

This worked perfectly fine, and prints without the need of flushing anything...
Why does Eclipse delay the output in C projects?

Comment: What happens if you add a few `fflush(stdout)` calls?

Comment: Have you made sure the input buffer is empty before you `scanf`? Try changing the format to `" %d"` (note the space)

Comment: @wallyk, I edited the main post.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, the problem is not premature `scanf`, but rather delay in the `printf`.

Comment: this is normal - your process is existing with data in the stdout buffer.  adding a delay before exiting will also circumvent the symptom.

Comment: Google "Eclipse mingw fflush stdout" . I think its a bug

Comment: Yup. it seems like it is a bug. :\ I'll switch to Visual Studio...

Comment: Its a bug in the eclipse IDE.
Bug 354098.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354098